# Hibernate - How to order result based on the property of another object

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Im new to java and hibernate.

**`ExpenseType.java`**

```
public class ExpenseType extends BaseDomain {
  private int companyId;
  private String name;
  private String description;
  private Company company;

  // Getters and Setters
}
```

**`Company.java`**

```
public class Company extends BaseDomain {
  private String name;
  private String address;
  private String contactNumber;
  private String emailAddress;

  // Getters and Setters
}
```

I have 2 ojects ExpenseType and Company. They have a `many-to-one` relationship. The 
mapping is in this file `expenseType.hbm.xml`.

**`expenseType.hbm.xml`**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="bp.ar.domain.hibernate.ExpenseType" table="EXPENSE_TYPE">   
      .
      .
      <property name="companyId">
        <column name="COMPANY_ID"/>
      </property>

      <many-to-one name="company" class="bp.ar.domain.hibernate.Company" fetch="select" insert="false" update="false" lazy="false">
        <column name="COMPANY_ID" not-null="true" />
      </many-to-one>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I have COMPANY_ID foreign key in my ExpenseType table.

In my implementation in the file  **`ExpenseTypeDaoImpl.java`** I do something like

```
@Override
public Collection<ExpenseType> getAll(int companyId, Collection<Company> companies,
     ExpenseTypeField orderBy) {
  DetachedCriteria dc = getDetachedCriteria();
  dc.addOrder(Order.asc("company"));
  dc.addOrder(Order.asc(orderBy.name()));
  return getAll(dc);
}
```

What I really want to happen is that the result for ExpenseType will be ordered based on the company name. What happens with code above is that it orders the ExpenseType based on tbe COMPANY_ID. I tried to use `dc.addOrder(Order.asc("company.name"));` but I get an error.

I have this error:

`org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: company.name of: bp.ar.domain.hibernate.ExpenseType`

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't map both company and companyId in your ExpenseType.  Just use company.

Comment: @MALfunction84 Thanks I didn't know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an alias to the relation before you can sort on its properties.  This is analogous to a SQL JOIN.

```
DetachedCriteria dc = getDetachedCriteria();
dc.createAlias("company", "company");
dc.addOrder(Order.asc("company.name"));
return getAll(dc);
```

Comment: Glad to help, @NinjaBoy.  I think you upvoted my answer instead of accepting it, though.

Comment: I had no idea you could answer something *too* quickly.  :P

Comment: I don't know why SO has to put some waiting time for users to accept the answer.